# If $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2 \sin (bx)}{ax-\sin x}=1$, then find $a,b$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2 \frac{\sin bx}{bx} (bx)}{x(\frac{ax}{x}-\frac{\sin x}{x})}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{bx^2 \frac{\sin bx}{bx}}{a-\frac{\sin x}{x}}$$
$$=0$$

Which is obviously wrong. I think I am suffering from lack of conceptual clarity in limits, so what exactly is going wrong in this question?

Comment: Do you know Taylor's formula  and equivalence of functions?

Comment: @ Aditya: If there is no $x^2$ term in numerator then $a=2b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$L=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2\sin bx}{ax-\sin x}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2(bx-b^3x^3/6+...)}{ax-x+x^3/6}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{bx^3-b^5 x^5/6}{ax-x+x^3/6}$$
If $L=1$, then $a=1,b=1/6.$

Answer (score 2):

The limit in your second step gives zero only for $a\neq 1$, therefore we need $a=1$ as a condition.

We can proceed as follows, since we have that $b\neq 0$ and

$$\frac{x^2 \sin (bx)}{ax-\sin x}=\frac{\sin bx}{bx}\frac{bx^3}{ax-\sin x}$$

and since $\frac{\sin bx}{bx} \to 1$ we need $\frac{bx^3}{ax-\sin x} \to 1$ which implies $a=1$ and finally we obtain

$$b=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}$$

which can be easily found by l'Hopital or by Taylor's expansion.

Comment: How did you obtain $b=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}$?

Comment: @Aditya Let indicate $c=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}$ and we have obtained as a condition $b/c=1 \implies b=c$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{x^2\sin bx}{ax-\sin x}=b\cdot\dfrac{\sin bx}{bx}\cdot\dfrac1{\dfrac{a-1}{x^2}+\dfrac{x-\sin x}{x^3}}$$

Now using [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%c3%b4pital-rule-or-series-expansion)

$a-1$ must be $=0$